# FOP, Getting constant performances on pdf generation

Tags: java, performance, apache-fop

We are having issues regarding fop (v0.95) performances on multiples calls. We are creating pdf containing a few images and our own fonts.

The first call is by far longer than the others and it's a problem for us. Here are some call examples (times are in ms) :

- Call #1  - Elapsed time = 13929
- Call #2  - Elapsed time = 2817
- Call #3  - Elapsed time = 3312
- Call #4  - Elapsed time = 1629
- Call #5  - Elapsed time = 1436
- Call #6  - Elapsed time = 1356
- Call #7  - Elapsed time = 911
- Call #8  - Elapsed time = 1244
- Call #9  - Elapsed time = 780
- Call #10 - Elapsed time = 895

We tried several thing to fix this :

1. Loading our font using the directory parameter instead or loading
   each font with the font tag
2. Setting stric-configuration to true
3. Setting strict-validation to false
4. Using the cache file (cache-file tag)

Nothing significantly improve performances on first call. Our only solution for the moment is to generate a fake pdf in the constructor so the first call will be artificially done at jvm start.

Do you have any suggestion to smooth the performances, and maybe some explanations about this behavior ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's an effect of Java class loading and JIT (just-in-time compiling), the so-called JVM warm-up. The JVM improves on the performance gradually as it sees optimization potential. If you run, say, 100 calls, you'll eventually see more or less constant performance. There's simply nothing you can do to change this, and the same applies to any Java application.

Maybe you can switch to the Client VM (-client as JVM parameter) if you're currently running the Server VM (which is default with a 64bit CPU). That might lessen the effect you see a bit, but probably not much.

Comment: I agree with you JIT improves performances after 4-5 calls (I see some references on the net which confirm my thoughts). However I can't explain why the first call takes ~14sec and the second takes 6 times less. Thanks.

Comment: @jakcam: in addition to JIT/Startup time (which *can* be significant) you also work on pre-filled buffers with all but the first calls (i.e. the OS has already read all the necessary resources and doesn't need to spin up your disk for the second, third, ... time around).

Answer (score 0):

How often do the underlying resources change in the generated PDF?

I've worked with FOP before and had roughly the same issues and never found a clean way around it (even though there may be one).

The one thing I would have tried in hindsight would be to generate the pdf whenever the underlying resources are persisted; and then serialize it as opposed to rendering on demand.  Then, whenever a request comes in just return the most recent serialized pdf.  Even though you might end up generating PDFs that are never used; it will drastically reduce the time for the user to get their pdf; likely more so than the times you're seeing now.